# Accessing the Value of a CheckBox in TableView

Tags: javafx

I'm having trouble getting the boolean value of whether a checkbox in a tableView for JavaFX is selected or not.

(Link to Image)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xgik.png

For some reason the when I getCellObservableValue() to get the CheckBox at index 1, I get null as the result.

```
//From SceneBuilder/JavaFX file
<TableColumn fx:id="labelColumn" prefWidth="112.57145690917969" text="Use 
as Label" />


//Setting Up Table, which displays everything correctly 
TableColumn<Integer,CheckBox>  labelColumn = (TableColumn<Integer, 
CheckBox>) elements.get("labelColumn");
labelColumn.setCellFactory(data -> new CheckBoxTableCell<>());
monitorTable.setEditable(true);



//Trying to Access, which gives null pointer exception
CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) labelColumn.getCellObservableValue(1);
System.out.println(cb.isSelected());
```

Comment: I am going to guess you need `setCellFactory`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217625/how-to-add-checkboxs-to-a-tableview-in-javafx

Comment: I posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53361763/javafx-tableview-checkbox-requires-focus/53362472#53362472) on a similar question that might help as well.

Answer (score 3):

[That method](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TableColumnBase.html#getCellObservableValue(int)) returns `null` if there's no `cellValueFactory` set. Besides, you should really have a model to hold this state—a `TableView` is just a view. Unlike the `TableViewSelectionModel`, which represents which items are selected solely in the context of the `TableView` itself, a column containing `CheckBox`es represents the "boolean state" *of a property of the model*. For example:

```
public class ToDoTask {

    private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "name");
    private final BooleanProperty complete = new SimpleBooleanProperty(this, "complete");

    // constructors, getters, setters, and property-getters omitted for brevity
}
```

A `TableView` for displaying that class could be configured like the following:

```
TableView<ToDoTask> table = new TableView<>();
table.setItems(...);

TableColumn<ToDoTask, String> nameCol = new TableColumn<>("Name");
nameCol.setCellValueFactory(features -> features.getValue().nameProperty());
table.getColumns().add(nameCol);

TableColumn<ToDoTask, Boolean> completeCol = new TableColumn<>("Complete");
completeCol.setCellValueFactory(features -> features.getValue().completeProperty());
completeCol.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(completeCol));
table.getColumns().add(completeCol);
```

You would then query if a task is complete by accessing the model:

```
table.getItems().get(...).isComplete();
```

Another option to setting the `cellValueFactory` is to register a `Callback` with the `CheckBoxTableCell`s themselves. See [`CheckBoxTableCell#forTableColumn(Callback)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/cell/CheckBoxTableCell.html#forTableColumn(javafx.util.Callback)).

---

Also, note that `getCellObservableValue()` returns an `ObservableValue`. A `CheckBox` is not an `ObservableValue`. If you weren't receiving `null` you'd be getting a `ClassCastException`.