# Add Checkbox to TableView Column

Tags: listview, javafx, boolean, checkboxlist

I am rebuilding a javafx desktop application in order to apply new functionality and remove useless code from the original. In particular a filtered listview with 2 columns: name and checkbox.

So far, I am unable to succesfully create checkboxes for each of the rows, I can only show a string value of "false / true" in the 2nd column.

Upon changing the methods used by the 2nd column from String to Boolean I start having issues compiling PersonTableController.class...

Person.class

```
package com.genx;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;

public class Person {

    public SimpleStringProperty firstName;
    public SimpleBooleanProperty selected;

    public Person(String firstName, boolean selected) {
        this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(firstName);
        this.selected = new SimpleBooleanProperty(selected);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public String getFirstName() {
       return firstName.get();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public boolean getSelected() {
       return selected.get();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public SimpleBooleanProperty selectedProperty() {
      return selected;
    }
}
```

PersonTablecontroller.class

```
package com.genx;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.collections.transformation.FilteredList;
import javafx.collections.transformation.SortedList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.SingleSelectionModel;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.CheckBoxTableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;


/**
 * View-Controller for the person table.
 */
public class PersonTableController {

    @FXML
    Button generate;
    @FXML
    Text status;
    @FXML
    TextField textVorname;
    @FXML
    TextField textNachname;
    @FXML
    TextField textUsergroup;
    @FXML
    TextField adname;
    @FXML
    CheckBox checkbox;
    @FXML
    CheckBox checkbox2;
    @FXML
    TextField filterField;
    @FXML
    TableView<Person> personTable = new TableView<Person>();
    @FXML   
    TableColumn<Person, String> firstNameColumn = new TableColumn<>("Roles Names");
    @FXML   
    TableColumn<Person, Boolean> lastNameColumn = new TableColumn<>("Selected");


    /**
     * Just add some sample data in the constructor.
     */
        ObservableList<Person> masterData = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
new Person("Hans", false), new Person("Ruth", false), new Person("Heinz", false), new Person("Cornelia", false), new Person("Werner", false), new Person("Lydia", false), new Person("Anna", false), new Person("Susan", true), new Person("Joan", false));

@FXML
private void initialize() {
// 0. Initialize the columns.
    personTable.setEditable(true);
    firstNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("firstName"));
    lastNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("selected"));
 lastNameColumn.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(lastNameColumn));
    lastNameColumn.setEditable(true);
    personTable.getColumns().addAll(firstNameColumn, lastNameColumn);
    personTable.setItems(masterData);

    // 1. Wrap the ObservableList in a FilteredList (initially display all data).
    FilteredList<Person> filteredData = new FilteredList<>(masterData, p -> true);

    // 2. Set the filter Predicate whenever the filter changes.
    filterField.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            filteredData.setPredicate(person -> {
                // If filter text is empty, display all persons.
                if (newValue == null || newValue.isEmpty()) {
                    return true;
                }

                // Compare first name and last name of every person with filter text.
                String lowerCaseFilter = newValue.toLowerCase();

                if (person.getFirstName().toLowerCase().indexOf(lowerCaseFilter) != -1) {
                    return true; // Filter matches first name.
                }
                return false; // Does not match.
            });
        });
        // 3. Wrap the FilteredList in a SortedList. 
        SortedList<Person> sortedData = new SortedList<>(filteredData); 
        // 4. Bind the SortedList comparator to the TableView comparator.       sortedData.comparatorProperty().bind(personTable.comparatorProperty());

        // 5. Add sorted (and filtered) data to the table.
        personTable.setItems(sortedData);
    }

    public void generateImpex() {
        Alert warning = new Alert(AlertType.WARNING, "Generating Impex!", ButtonType.YES, ButtonType.CANCEL);
        warning.showAndWait();
    }
}
```

In it´s current state, I cannot compile the controller as it cannot find Person.class for some reason...

If the Boolean property & methods are changed to String in Person.class then I can compile the jar using this code for PersonTableController.class:

```
package com.genx;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.collections.transformation.FilteredList;
import javafx.collections.transformation.SortedList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.SingleSelectionModel;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.CheckBoxTableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;


/**
 * View-Controller for the person table.
 */
public class PersonTableController {

    @FXML
    Button generate;
    @FXML
    Text status;
    @FXML
    TextField textVorname;
    @FXML
    TextField textNachname;
    @FXML
    TextField textUsergroup;
    @FXML
    TextField adname;
    @FXML
    CheckBox checkbox;
    @FXML
    CheckBox checkbox2;
    @FXML
    private TextField filterField;
    @FXML
    private TableView<Person> personTable;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Person, String> firstNameColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Person, String> lastNameColumn; // TableColumn<Person, Boolean> lastNameColumn;

    private ObservableList<Person> masterData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public PersonTableController() {
        masterData.add(new Person("Hans", "false"));
        masterData.add(new Person("Ruth", "false"));
        masterData.add(new Person("Heinz", "false"));
        masterData.add(new Person("Cornelia", "false"));
        masterData.add(new Person("Werner", "false"));
        masterData.add(new Person("Lydia", "false"));
        masterData.add(new Person("Anna", "false"));
        masterData.add(new Person("Stefan", "false"));
        masterData.add(new Person("Martin", "false"));
        masterData.add(new Person("Joni", "false"));
        masterData.add(new Person("Chachi", "false"));
        masterData.add(new Person("Phillip", "false"));
        masterData.add(new Person("Susan", "true"));
        masterData.add(new Person("Joan", "false"));
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the table columns and sets up sorting and filtering.
     */
    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        // 0. Initialize the columns.
        firstNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().firstNameProperty());
        lastNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().lastNameProperty());
        // 1. Wrap the ObservableList in a FilteredList (initially display all data).
        FilteredList<Person> filteredData = new FilteredList<>(masterData, p -> true);
        // 2. Set the filter Predicate whenever the filter changes.
        filterField.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            filteredData.setPredicate(person -> {
                // If filter text is empty, display all persons.
                if (newValue == null || newValue.isEmpty()) {
                    return true;
                }
                String lowerCaseFilter = newValue.toLowerCase();            
                if (person.getFirstName().toLowerCase().indexOf(lowerCaseFilter) != -1) {
                    return true; // Filter matches first name.
                }
                return false; // Does not match.
            });
        });
        // 3. Wrap the FilteredList in a SortedList. 
        SortedList<Person> sortedData = new SortedList<>(filteredData);

        // 4. Bind the SortedList comparator to the TableView   sortedData.comparatorProperty().bind(personTable.comparatorProperty());

        // 5. Add sorted (and filtered) data to the table.
        personTable.setItems(sortedData);
    }

    public void generateImpex() {
        Alert warning = new Alert(AlertType.WARNING, "Generating Impex!", ButtonType.YES, ButtonType.CANCEL);
        warning.showAndWait();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you clear out what you really want?

Comment: @AzmahQi I need to change the TableView 2nd column so instead of showing true or false as string, show a checkbox representing the boolean value.

Comment: Can you share us the error you get when you try to use a Boolean?

Comment: The error is "cannot find symbol <Person>" wherever Person.class is called... might be something about the order or how I am declaring things?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaFx Tableview checkbox requires focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53361763/javafx-tableview-checkbox-requires-focus). See if my answer there helps.

Comment: Do one step after the other: you the compiler can't find the Person class, then there's something wrong with your project - try a clean build and triple check that the classes are where you expect them (from the code you are showing here, they should) Fix that before you jump for the checkboxTableCell

Comment: @Zephyr thanks a lot, although not exactly the same question, your example helped me to get this working. The only issue I see now is that I am only able to navigate and toggle the first checkbox in the list when I use TAB and SPACE.

Comment: @kleopatra Turns out it was an error that had been occurring for a while, I might of forgot from other times... I was not compiliing the Controller from the root directory of the app... as soon as I did that, the error ceased. Thanks for your help!